# Wi-Fi no longer works after abrupt shutdown

Tags: networking, wifi, drivers, intel, iwlwifi

Repost of my question deleted from askubuntu for being off-topic because my distro is Ubuntu Cinnamon Remix.

##### Description of the problem

I forgot to plug in my laptop as it was syncing files from a distant machine overnight. It inevitably ran out of battery and went into hibernation mode.
Once on, I could no longer connect to Wi-Fi. I *can* connect to the internet through ethernet, but this is not ideal as it uses a dongle that takes up my charging port, and also limits mobility. I've followed many troubleshooting guides, including (but not limited to):

[1](https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-ubuntu-wifi-not-working/) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538498/wifi-suddenly-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) [3](https://superuser.com/questions/81750/ubuntu-wireless-driver-reinstall) [4](https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/) [5](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252913) [6](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/ubuntu-20-04-Intel-ax200-Failed-to-run-INIT-ucode-110/m-p/1266491) [7](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/wifi-stopped-working-iwlwifi-failed-to-start-init-ucode-110/82828/2) [8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331204/wifi-suddenly-disappeared-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts) [9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318556/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-no-wifi) [10](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=232970)

##### What I've tried so far

I've tried reinstalling `network-manager` through APT and `backport-iwlwifi` from source.

Following link 10, I have tried re-downloading all of the `iwlwifi*.ucode` files from `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/` and replacing the existing ones in `/lib/firmware`, to no avail.

Following link 1, I have tried loading the Ubuntu Cinnamon ISO (the ISO of my distribution) onto a USB thumbdrive and installing drivers from there. The iso is recognized by my system as a virtual CD-ROM drive, but the ***Installable from CD-ROM/DVD*** option in the Software & Updates dialog remains grey and unresponsive, and says "insert the medium into the drive". I've also tried mounting the ISO with AcetoneISO, for the same result.

##### Relevant diagnostic information

**System info:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Kernel:         Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Kernel Params:  ro, quiet, splash, resume=UUID=b8febb47-e2f1-41f7-bf30-bce7e55e6566, resume_offset=9285632, vt.handoff=7

Desktop:        Cinnamon

SecureBoot disabled
```

**Relevant output of `lspci`**, which detects my Wi-Fi controller:

```
aa:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

**Full Output of `rfkill list all`**, which does not list a Wi-Fi device:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**Relevant Output of `lsmod`:**

```
iwlmvm                729088  0
mac80211             1249280  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               536576  1 iwlmvm
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              999424  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
compat                 16384  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
```

**Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`:**

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
```

**Content of `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*`:** Empty

**Full output of `ip link show`**, with no Wi-Fi network interface:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enxa0cec8e71b91: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:ce:c8:e7:1b:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**`iwconfig`:**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enxa0cec8e71b91  no wireless extensions.
```

**`dmesg | grep iwlwifi`** returns 258 lines, with some repetitions, so here's what looks relevant:

```
[    2.570841] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    2.570842] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:10878:f4df8641
[    2.683312] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.699594] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x400410, cnv-id 0x400410 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    2.699718] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: PCI dev 2725/0024, rev=0x420, rfid=0x10d000
[    2.728800] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-80.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.729650] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.729668] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: WRT: Invalid time point 28 for host command TLV
[    2.729697] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: WRT: Failed to allocate TLV 0x1000007, ret -22, (ext=0)
[    2.729699] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.41
[    2.730098] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: loaded firmware version 79.27f1c37b.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-79.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.915335] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[...]
[    3.063768] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: loaded PNVM version 64acdc51
[    3.314551] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    3.314557] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[...]
```

I do not have a dual boot with any other OS.

##### Closing statements

My best guess is that I need to reinstall a corrupted driver, but I just can't figure out what exactly to reinstall. Any help sorting this situation out would be greatly appreciated.

##### Update

Thanks to Freddy for the suggestions. I've tried [deleting `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm`](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13), deleting the `.ucode` files for the versions more recent than 59, deleting everything and re-importing the latest driver binary [provided by intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html), and every combination of the above, to no avail.

Here is some of the new output of `dmesg`:

```
[    2.939097] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: PCI dev 2725/0024, rev=0x420, rfid=0x10d000
[    2.941107] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-80.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.941122] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-79.ucode failed with error -2
[...] # same thing from 78 to 61, all these driver files are currently missing in /lib/firmware
[    2.941910] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.942903] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.942925] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    2.943170] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.994764] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
```

I posted the rest on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Au1wvJUc). So we see that the new firmware versions are being skipped and it's loading version 59, but something goes wrong after that.

I also found some old USB Wi-Fi antennae:

- TRENDNET AC600 which I've gotten working out of the box with several other Linux machines
- TP-Link Archer T2U Plus which isn't supported out of the box but I got a [custom driver](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git) working for it on other Linux machines

Neither of these work. They do show up in `lsusb` but nothing in `rfkill`, and the LEDs on the antennae don't turn on. So it seems that the problem isn't limited to the built-in Wi-Fi card. What could be causing system-wide failure to handle Wi-Fi devices?

### Update 2

The problem is fixed, I'm not sure why. I performed a pretty big upgrade, most notably including the following packages: `linux-generic, linux-image-generic, linux-headers-generic, linux-generic-hwe-22.04, linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04, linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04, linux-generic-hwe-20.04, linux-libc-dev`. I restarted my computer after the update which booted me into GRUB (it usually just boots into Ubuntu). I remembered someone mentioning that a similar problem needed fast boot disabled to be fixed, so I took the opportunity to boot into my BIOS and disable fast boot. I rebooted, and now Wi-Fi works.

Here is some updated info in case this helps anyone:

**New system info:**

```
Linux 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Kernel Params:  [same as before but remove vt.handoff=7]
```

**`lsmod`:**

```
iwlmvm                569344  0
mac80211             1249280  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               450560  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              974848  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  1 wmi_bmof
```

**Full output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`**:

```
[    2.666632] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'disable_msix' ignored
[    2.670998] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.681512] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.681647] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-65.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.681770] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.681928] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.681999] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.682072] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-61.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.682090] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.683225] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.683248] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    2.683538] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.758154] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    2.913333] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    2.981488] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0: base HW address: c4:bd:e5:1b:52:4c
[    2.999710] iwlwifi 0000:aa:00.0 wlp170s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I did a `diff` on the `iwlwifi-*` files in `/lib/firmware` and a backup I had made, and they're apparently identical.

Comment: I can only see that your firmware is pretty new (`iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-79.ucode`) and you're running a 5.15 kernel. I'm running a 6.0.12 kernel (Debian 11 with kernel + firmware-iwlwifi from backports) and only have version 66 in my firmware directory. The official one from [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) has version 59. Ubuntu Jammy [up to 71](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/linux-firmware/filelist).

Comment: Try the older firmware versions. Rename/move the latest one as root, reboot and see what happens (`dmesg`), the driver will pick the latest matching one. Loop. If that doesn't help, rename the `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` file, see [bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212371#c13). If you ask me, people always have trouble with Intel's AX210 card. It's not a good card.

Comment: Well done! I'm curious if the latest firmware also works with pnvm. Please move Update2 into the answer box and don't forget to accept it (see [Can I answer my own question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: I don't feel like my *question* is answered. My *problem* is *solved*, but the origin remains a mystery and "just update" isn't helpful advice when something breaks out of nowhere and there are no updates available. Do you reckon I should still answer my own question? I would have marked this as "closed" if that were a thing.

Comment: No, leave it as is if you think it's not answered. I thought that [fast-boot](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled) was the cause. At least it would explain things...